# isPalindrome not showing output and isPalindrome function is not tested with the string input as the string argument

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void convert(string& str) {
    for (size_t i =0; i <str.length(); i++) {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
}
bool isPalindrome(string str) {
    int length = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[length -1 -i]) {
            cout << str << " is not a palindrome" << endl;
            return false;
        } else if (str[i] == str[length -1 -i] && toupper(str[i]) == toupper(str [length -1 -i])) {
                cout << str << " is a palindrome" << endl;
        } // for loop
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main () {

    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    convert(str);
    isPalindrome(str);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the output box in a homework grader for my coding assignment is showing blank but when I run my program it says whether or not it is Palindrome. Also the automatic grader also searches my code for a specific pattern like .+*isPalindrome(\"Madam\").+* but the automatic grader says I only got 10 points because my code had a specific pattern of \s\isPalindrome(string str). I am really confused and do not know why my output is being shown blank and the automatic grader is looking for a specific pattern but I do not know what pattern???

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean the program is not outputting anything, it actually prints out whether a given string is a palindrome or not. Also we don't know what it means "only 10 points".

Comment: Sorry, so for my homework it has an input and output box and the homework grader has words it uses to test the isPalindrome function which are (madam, abba, 22, 67876, 444244, trymeuemyrt) but my function does output whether or not its Palindrome but it is not showing up on the homework output box which is blank. .

Comment: perhaps the grader takes the return value of the program to be the answer; that would mean your ```main()``` needs to return 0 when the given string is a palindrome and value different from 0 when the string is not a palindrome

Comment: Fwiw, that code can't reliably compile. `std::string` is in `<string>` which you're not including.  Also, your function shouldn't be reporting; it should simply return true or false. `main` should be reporting whether the input line was a palindrome by actually doing something with the result of the call rather than ignoring it.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what that means I've been working on this homework for like the past 5 days and its driving me insane lol and its also due on December 3rd so how would I possibly write that in the main function if it is Palindrome or not? Thank you

Comment: `if (isPalindrome(str)) std::cout << str << " is a palindrome\n"; else ...` etc. That reporting belongs in `main`. Your function's sole purpose is to determine whether to return `true` or `false` based on the input provided.

Comment: replace the ```isPalindrome(str); return 0;``` with ```return isPalindrome(str);```, that should do the trick

Comment: It's a good idea to also replace ```#include<string.h>``` with ```#include<string>```.

Comment: Yeah I tried Ashley solution it didn't work and WhozCraig sorry If i suck at programming but I still do not understand what to delete from my isPalindrome function and what to add to my int main , could any of ya'll possibly rework my code on like Gifthub and show me what to do? I am just lost.

Comment: I now see I made a mistake in my solution, which would have caused it to give wrong answers to any input; e.g. report 'madam' as not a palindrome. If that's the case, the return statement should be ```return ! isPalindrome(str);```. If it's not the case, are there any instructions provided with the automatic grader that specify how's it supposed to be used?

Comment: It says "your program should print a message indicating if a string is a palindrome: madam is a palindrome " and the automatic homework grader has tasks which tests my coding pattern and it test my program with strings like madam, 22, trymeuemyrt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are just misunderstanding the output terminal. Everything is working fine just required to ask the user to enter a value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void convert(string& str) {
    for (size_t i =0; i <str.length(); i++) {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
}
bool isPalindrome(string str) {
    int length = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[length -1 -i]) {
            cout << str << " is not a palindrome" << endl;
            return false;
        } else if (str[i] == str[length -1 -i] && toupper(str[i]) == toupper(str [length -1 -i])) {
                cout << str << " is a palindrome" << endl;
        } // for loop
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main () {

    string str;
    cout<<"Enter a string to check is it palindrome or not."<<endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    convert(str);
    isPalindrome(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203428/discussion-on-answer-by-rijaul-sk-ispalindrome-not-showing-output-and-ispalindro).

Answer (score 0):

The grader wants to see the code pattern so we have to check each string one by one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string str);

int main()
{
    if (isPalindrome("Madam"))
            cout << "Madam" << " is a palindrome." << endl;
    else
            cout << "Madam" << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
            
    if (isPalindrome("abBa"))
            cout << "abBa" << " is a palidrome." << endl;
    else
            cout << "abBa" << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
    if (isPalindrome("22"))
            cout << "22" << " is a palindrome." << endl;
    else
        cout << "22" << " is not a palindrome," << endl;
    if (isPalindrome("67876"))
            cout << "67876" << " is a palindrome." << endl;
    else
            cout << "67876" << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
    if (isPalindrome("444244"))
            cout << "444244" << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
    else
            cout << "444244" << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
    if (isPalindrome("trYmeuemyRT"))
            cout << "trYmeuemyRT" << " is a palindrome." << endl;
    else
            cout << "trYmeuemyRT" << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
  string aStr[] = {"madam",
                   "abba", 
                   "22",
                   "67876",
                   "444244", 
                   "trymeuemyrt"};

  for (int i=0; i<static_cast<int>(sizeof(aStr)/sizeof(aStr[0])); i++) {
    
    if(isPalindrome(aStr[i]))
      cout << aStr[i] << " is a palindrome." << endl;
    else
      cout << aStr[i] << " is not a palindrome." << endl;
}

return 0;
}
bool isPalindrome(string str)
{
int length = str.length();

for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++){
    if (tolower(str[i]) != tolower(str[length - 1 - i]))
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```